# Como melhorar minhas perguntas?

Tags: suporte

Recentemente tive problemas em um projeto legado que estou trabalhando e tentei buscar ajuda para dois problemas pontuais que eu tive, e, mesmo sem receber downvotes ou pedidos de mudanças, não obtive resposta em nenhuma, mesmo imaginando se tratar de coisas "simples"

Gostaria de saber se o problema está nas perguntas e como posso melhorar, ou foi apenas falta de sorte de encontrar alguém que soubesse como resolver?

as perguntas?

[asp:Textbox type=“date” não é preenchido](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/433278/asptextbox-type-date-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-preenchido)

[ASP.NETX evento onkeydown condicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/434218/asp-netx-evento-onkeydown-condicional)

Comment: O titulo sugere uma duplicata, mas por se tratar de algo mais especifico para o meu caso, imagino que não se enquadre, certo?

Comment: Tem casos que o problema é só que ninguém sabe, acha que dará trabalho demais ou não é algo que vale o esforço de ajudar. A pergunta precisa ser clara, não sei se a sua é tão clara assim, mas também não é tão "jogada" que meraça negativou ou ser fechada. Tem caso que nada que faça vai atrair gente pra responder, nem colocando recompensa, em alguns casos chamará gente que não sabe responder bem, mas tem caso que você precisa tornar a pergunta atrativa para ter gente interessada. Perguntas *boring* costumam ficar abandonadas. O problema não chama atenção. Nem estou julgando as suas.

Comment: Uma das perguntas tem menos de um dia, e realmente acho que poucos trabalham com asp.net "normal", então talvez sejam poucos os que saberão resolver os seus problemas. Sobre a pergunta me parece um problema de HTML e não do asp.net, então respondi: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/434332/3635

Comment: Esta pergunta https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/434218/3635, somente a parte que "você fez" no final q ficou um pouco confusa, mas vou ler com calma depois. De qualquer forma sobre os problemas gerais é q hoje em dia tem muita pouca gente nessa área de "asp.net classico", então talvez as pessoas até saibam usar, mas fiquem com receio por não usarem a algum tempo.

Comment: Eu imaginei que não seria tão simples achar ajuda com asp classico, mas fica a preocupação de, como o Manieiro disse, não fazer perguntas _boring_ ou não ficar claro o suficiente para os outros, eu tento me policiar, mas não é um exercício tão simples